# eGit and gitHub detached HEAD error

Tags: git, github, egit

I created a repo in github: project1

I created a java project in eclipse project1 and make: team - share project - git - I named it project1 [image]

Now, I double click rlocal repo in eclipse and created: new remote - configure push - named it origin and enter the URI and credentials. I changed something and did the commit and push, it worked fine, it did the changes in the github repo.I change

[image]

But when I did a commit in the github, and try to fetch the changes in my local repo it gave me some errors I do not understand: It didnt show the changes in the code, but created a  "file" named FETCH_HEAD,

[image]

when a double click the file and choose checkout the changes are applied but it said the HEAD is detached. Thanks in advance!!!

[image]

Comment: this is *exactly* why you should use the CLI.   eGit is a biatch to use by itself. I'd recommend using eGit only for the icons that it provides

Comment: Another thing a notice is that if I do the steps I wrote above, the pull option in the rigth click menu is disable but if I did a clone from the repo on github the option is available a I can make the pull and push and the changes are applied. I understand that fetch = pull + merge,  am I ok?

Answer (score 0):

EGit is very confusing. When you share a project through your method you are creating a git repo in your target directory. This does not create an initial commit leaving your repo without a HEAD pointer.

I had the same issue when I decided to use EGit. Usually I create a .gitignore or a README.md and commit them to create an initial commit.